# Installing Pantheon on another system, lock screen doesn't work? / How to switch to io.elementary.greeter from gdm3?

Tags: greeter, pantheon, lock

As described in title, lock screen doesn't work. I can't lock with Applications > Lock, or by closing the laptop lid, but running `io.elementary.greeter` in the terminal works...sort of. It displays on my desktop underneath all other running applications.

I suspect this has to do with me using gdm3 as the default greeter, but I can't change it to io.elementary.greeter using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. The option isn't there.

What do I do?